# similar method in Camera2 like onPreviewFrame in Camera

Tags: android, android-camera, deprecated, android-camera2

In class, Camera was a method like

```
public abstract void onPreviewFrame (byte[] data,  Camera camera)
```

where I can to `receivebyte[]` data and change picture
but `Camera` is depreciated at this moment

Is there a method in `Camera 2` like onPreviewFrame, which returns data
I want to impose a filter on a picture in TextureView from Camera

Comment: If you find my answer is helpful then please vote for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In camera2 API has been changed completely. You can grab frames inside `OnImageAvailableListener`

Here I post my part of working code to grab the frames.

```
readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

                  image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                if(image == null){
                    //System.out.println("it is null image"); // image reader did not get new image
                    return;
                }
                Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                  if(planes[0].getBuffer() == null){ // here 0 indicates first target I set in outputSurfaces list
                      System.out.println("it is null object reference of planes");
                    return;
                  }
                 //.... do whatever you want here

                //After you are done with an image then close it 
               image.close(); 

               }
}
```

For more info, you can have a look to [Google samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

Comment: Image.Plane[] I turn to bitmap(change this bitmap), then How set bitmap to textureView ?

Comment: `textureView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));`